# javascript not loading using express static

Tags: javascript, express, static, onload, src

first let me explain that i am not expecting myself to submit this as i had referred and experimented repeatedly on countless attempts but still i could not get the javascript and images served via expressjs. The project folders structure:

```
[root] (the project folder)
 |server.js <-- the main file    
 |[staticFiles] (contains js img files)
 |[html]        (contains html files)
 |[js]          (contains javascripts)
 |[node_modules] (library home)
```

server.js: (the main file)

```
var express = require('lib/express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 65000;

var bodyParser = require('./node_modules/body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var cons = require('consolidate');
var path = require('path');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', "./html");
app.use('/user1', require('./js/routes/user1'));

// here i'd tried various combinations:
var staticPathFinal = express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'staticFiles'));
app.use(staticPathFinal);
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'staticFiles')));
// app.use(express.static(__dirname, 'staticFiles'));
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/staticFiles'));
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/staticFiles/')); // 2123
// app.use(express.static('staticFiles')); // 2159
// app.use('/user', express.static('staticFiles'));
// app.use('/user', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'staticFiles')));

app.listen(port);
```

[user1: ./js/routes/user1]

```
[js]
 |routes    
  |user1.js
```

code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, resp) {
    resp.render("srcEvent1");
}
```

[html: srcEvent.html] with basics removed for easy reading:

```
<head lang="en">
<title>srcEvent.html</title>
    <script src="srcEvent.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="srcEvent_alert()">
    <h1>page info: this shall activate alert from srcEvent.js:</h1>
</body>
```

[staticFiles] (folder containing javascript & img)

srcEvent.js

```
function srcEvent_alert(){
    alert('srcEvent_alert:0006:');
}
```

on server run ok expects connection.

on browser url [localhost:65000/user1]

```
result1: without <script src="srcEvent.js"></script> page loaded :-)
result2: with <script src="srcEvent.js"></script> page could not load :-(((
```

that made me spent many stressful countless hours crossed project timeline over days experimenting wrt answers from stackoverflow and elsewhere but simply mine did not work though the setup seemed to conform to those googled references.

someone please help me out of that dungeon.

thanks.

daniel

Comment: Why are you requiring npm modules by relative path instead using configured entry point in it's package.json?. For example, «var express = require("express");»

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using relative path (without slash) `<script src="srcEvent.js">` so it tries to find js at `/staticFiles/user/srcEvent.js` Try to change it to `<script src="/srcEvent.js">` and see if it works.

Also I would recommend you to use `developer tools` inside the browser and see which url exactly it tries to load (from network panel)

P.S. You can use `require('express')` instead of  `require('./node_modules/express/lib/express')` because node itself looks for the dependencies inside `node_modules` folders

Comment: i did that already as shown with several of them but one at a time: <script src="../js/srcEvent.js"></script>
        <script src="./srcEvent.js"></script>
        <script src="/srcEvent.js"></script>
        <script src="/staticFiles/srcEvent.js"></script>

Comment: with firefox dev console network i see: GET srcEvent.js localhost:65000 & GET user1 localhost:65000

Comment: i did as per your advise changed to require('express') rerun server ok but the srcEvent.js when in-use browser beach-ball spin non-stop.

Comment: allo some one else who knows and can provide a solution ?